# Worklight: direct update and WL Server sends duplicate responses

Tags: duplicates, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

I am experiencing that whenever there is a direct Update, App is going to be refreshed and showing main/login page. If user is already logged in then he sees a login page again.

But the big problem is, if he/she tries to login after update then App do not login and user has to click 2nd time. After this, user gets logged in but WL server sends two replies.

for example, login step contains 3 adapter calls , now WL server is sending 6 replies....duplicate reply of each call.

Please suggest:
(1) How I prevent WL Server to not send duplicate replies ? 
(2) If Direct update refreshes the App and takes user to the main/login page due to App refresh, then how i clear user session on server?

I am using adapter based authentication. This issue only happens when a direct update has been received. Otherwise App works fine, no duplicate records, no double login click issue.

Thanks

Comment: is this resolved by now?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved by changing the form authentication type to Adapter based authentication and now duplicate responses are not coming any more.

Thanks to Idan.

Comment: I know this is a bit chatty, but Idan rocks :)